# How can I pass a hidden html element`s value to jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, datatable

I have a hidden element with a PHP dynamic value in HTML and I would like to get it in jQuery when I click in a row of the table where the value is. Right now I can click on a row and get the value of the first column of that row but it prints the entire element as a string.

```
<td>
  <input type="hidden" name="zyx" value="test id" />
</td>
```

**jquery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
        $('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
            var data = table.row(this).data();
            alert(data[0]);      
        });
    });
```

this is what it prints: "`<input type="hidden" name="zyx" value="test id">`"

Comment: $("#hiddenField").val();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `.find` to find the first input inside the first `td` found inside the clicked row:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    const $input = $(this).find('td:first-child input');
    console.log($input.val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
    <tbody>
      <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="xyz" value="value 1" />Value 1</td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="wxy" value="value 2" />Value 2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```